# Vimeo Integration Advance API - HTML5

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, api, vimeo

I have created vimeo account and app with video upload also got approved.
When I try to upload video to vimeo server, I unable to upload.
I don't know how Oauth works.Please find my code below.

```
function test()
  {$.support.cors = true;
    var formData = {method:"vimeo.videos.upload.getQuota",format:"xml"};
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2",
           xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }, 
          data : formData,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          crossDomain : true,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {              
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic xsd"}

    });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: I got response as "Invalid consumer Key", Can you explain me how to authenticate request in client side.

Comment: Have you tried adding the properties `username` and `password` with their respective values inside the `$.ajax` call?

Answer (score 1):

The Vimeo Advanced API Uses OAuth 1.0, which is a complex system that **can not** securely be implemented completely client side.

Vimeo's new API also can not be securely implemented completely client side, but overall is a better plan for writing new code.

For the new API, you can (via the server) ask for an html form and include it in your html. Again, do not make the api request on the client or you will be exposing your authentication tokens. Vimeo does not yet offer a secure way of using these tokens in your browser.

For more information on the simple uploader, you can read the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload#http-post-uploading)

Comment: See here for an example of how to upload to Vimeo securely from Javascript/Ajax: https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:280469